# Using an account id instead of "tokenized" source with Stripe Connect

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

Following the guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/quickstart

Step 2 shows creating an account ending with

```
curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=xx\
  -d code="{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}" \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code
The response includes the user’s account ID, which you’ll need in Step 3. (You can also find it in the Dashboard; it’ll be something like acct_9kYI2P9tA3ruC9Ig.)
```

Now I have an `acct...`, great. In Step 3, however, the `source` field is a `token`.

Do accounts work for source? Is there a conversion process to go from account -> tokenized source?

```
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.api_key = 'xxx'

charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: "usd",
  source: "tok_visa",
  transfer_data: {
    destination: "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
  },
})
The example uses a test token—tok_visa—but you could tokenize a test card using Stripe.js and Elements or Stripe Checkout instead.
```

Comment: Did you include your actual Stripe test API keys in this question?

Comment: It was from a test account but thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the example in Step 3 they are charging some card and transferring money to some connected account. If you need to transfer money *from* the connected account check https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits section instead:

```rb
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: 1500,
  currency: 'usd',
  source: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
})
```

Comment: Yes, but please refer to the documentation - there are a bunch of limitations and additional requirements (like extra costs, for example) for using accounts debits...

Comment: The example does not show the charging channeling into the recipient account with a destination. Is this possible?